# How to run two light wallets at the same time?

Tags: wallet

I would like to open two (or multiple) instances of the light wallet so I can do more transactions and validate other people's. Is this possible somehow? At the moment I have to logout from one and login into the other one which is a pain.

Comment: Hi Ando, which system are you running the wallet on? Smartphone, PC, (cloud) server?

Comment: I'm on a mac. (thanks for the suggested edits)

Answer (score 2):

Right now there is not a great way to do this in a single instance on your PC. Your best bet will be to open a VM and open another instance of the IOTA wallet there.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into the api for a potential headless solution in JS.